# Material Design scaling font

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I'm using Google's *new* [`Material Design`](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) in a website I'm making. I have some questions concerning the [typography](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html) rules they provide.

To simulate their values provided in the [typography-link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html) I've made a css file to easily use their given values. This css file looks like so:

```
.display4{
    font-size: 112px;
    font-weight: 300;
    opacity: 0.54;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: -0.089em;
}
.display3{
    font-size: 56px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.54;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: -0.089em;
}
.display2{
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.54;
    line-height: 1.06em;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
.display1{
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.54;
    line-height: 1.176em;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
h1{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.87;
    line-height: 1.333em;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
h2{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.87;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
h3{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.87;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
core-drawer-panel:not([narrow]) h3{
    font-size: 15px;
}
.body2{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.87;
    line-height: 1.714em;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
.body2:not([narrow]){
    font-size: 13px;
}
p{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.87;
    line-height: 1.174em;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
core-drawer-panel:not([narrow]) p{
    font-size: 13px;
}
h4{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.54;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
.menu{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.87;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
core-drawer-panel:not([narrow]) .menu{
    font-size: 13px;
}
.button{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.87;
    white-space: nowrap;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

One issue I'm still having is with the calculation of the size of `letter-spacing` (provided in the bottom-most section *Tracking and Kerning*), but I guess this will be clarified in a further stage of the project.

The question that arises is the following - the values they give are `Scalable Pixels`, so that they can be easily scaled. Unfortunately I'm not really sure how to do this. Currently I've just done a 1-1 translation of sp to px. I've already converted *all* the other values to em (which I have come to believe is relative to the font-size).

I want my website to have two buttons, to increase/decrease overall font-size. I've checked a website I know supports multiple font sizes, but they just have separate stylesheets, something I'm hoping to circumvent.

So my question: how should I set up my css file to be easily scalable and how should I scale it with javascript/css?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `rem` units for font sizes, so that they will be easily scaleable relative to the font-size of the root element (mostly the `<html>` element).

If you want IE8 support, provide a pixel value as fallback like so:

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

All you have to do then, is increasing the font-size of the root element via JavaScript.